# E se... cosa significa all'inizio della frase?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Nel linguaggio colloquiale parecchie frasi iniziano con "e se...".

Per esempio:

"E se ti dicessi che sei pazzo?"

"E se Alice venisse a casa tua due volte alla settimana?"

Ma dico, cosa vuol dire dire così all'inizio, interrompendo il discorso che viene fatto prima, saltando ad un nuovo argomento, con "e se"?

Sarei grato se qualcuno me lo può spiegare.

Sembra quasi che uno possa fare una proposta con "e se". È vero. Quando lo posso dire?

Grazie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Di sicuro non è una frase che puoi usare per iniziare un discorso

Prendiamo la seconda frase, potresti usarla in questo contesto:

Alice è brava in matematica, Marco no.

> Marco dice a sua madre: "Ho problemi a fare gli esercizi di
>   matematica".
>
> Sua madre gli risponde:
>
> "E se Alice venisse a casa due volte alla settimana (per aiutarti)?"

Hai ragione a dire che si usa per fare proposte (o meglio, controproposte) oppure per fare domande retoriche in modo provocatorio (come nel primo caso).

Comment: Ma non potrei iniziare una conversazione dicendo qualcosa come "E se andassimo a cena fuori stasera?"?

Comment: Suonerebbe strano, sarebbe meglio "Che ne dici se andassimo a cena fuori stasera?"

"E se..." presuppone (di solito) una conversazione precedente

Comment: A me non suona strano, ma semplicemente una scelta di stile e/o di registro, proprio perché la "E" di apertura può indicare una conversazione già cominciata. Personalmente, mi capita di usarla sia nel parlato che nello scritto.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con Benedetta, anzi è un modo abbastanza comune di fare proposte.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @Benedetta. Ci sono casi in cui "e se" può essere usato per iniziare un discorso. Potrei proporre a qualcuno di fare qualcosa, per esempio al posto di guardare la televisione annoiati. "E se andassimo al cinema? C'è un nuovo film."

Answer (score 2):

"E se" -- "Cosa accadrebbe se...?", oppure "E' possibile che...?", "Ti sembra ragionevole che...?".

Quindi, sì, si può usare per "interrompere" una discussione con una proposta:

```
A: "Andiamo al mare."
B: "Andiamo in montagna."
C: "E se rimanessimo a casa?"
```

Si può rafforzare in questo significato di "rottura" con *invece*: "E se invece...?".

Equivale all'inglese *What if (instead)...?*